# Requiring timezone information when deserialising DateTimeOffset

Tags: c#, json, datetime, .net-core

I am trying to validate data I get from an API endpoint. The user should be able to send in a `DateTimeOffset`. Currently I am using my own implementation of `JsonConverter` to validate the correct format of the `DateTimeOffset`. I have tried multiple date time formats but none of them quite work as I am wanting.

```
"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffK"
```

This works for:

```
2010-01-01T01:01:01.000
2010-01-01T01:01:01.000Z
2010-01-01T01:01:01.000+01:00
```

The problem is, it is not enforcing a time offset or Z to be specified as seen in the top example, apart from that it works great.

```
"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffzzz"
```

This works for only:

```
2010-01-01T01:01:01.000+01:00
```

It doesn't accept Z as a time offset. Is there a `DateTimeOffset` format which I could specify to only accept the following:

```
2010-01-01T01:01:01.000Z
2010-01-01T01:01:01.000+01:00
```

Comment: Do You really need a DateTimeOffset?  When reading data which includes a Timezone it doesn't make any sense to include an offset.  The timezone is the offset.

Comment: Your first example once parsed with "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffK" will have a `DateTime.Kind` of `Unspecified` unlike the other two, so you could use that property to reject the input.

Comment: @steve16351 that's a pretty good solution there. Could you put it as an answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the ["K"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#KSpecifier) format specifier, an empty string for that part equates to a `DateTime.Kind` of `Unspecified`.

So, that's why it still parses without error, but in the parsed `DateTime` we can tell the difference by checking the [DateTime.Kind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.kind?view=netframework-4.8) property, and reject the input if it is unspecified. For example:

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact("2010-01-01T01:01:01.000", "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffK", null);
if (date.Kind == DateTimeKind.Unspecified)
    throw new ArgumentException("You must specify a time offset");
```